# I have created a secret with type Opaque in openshift to connect to database. The user with name appuser is not able to create stored procedures

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2

I have created a secret with type Opaque in openshift to connect to database. The secret file is quite simple and it stores the username and password for the database connection. The user with name appuser is not able to create stored procedures. Is there a way I can elevate the access of this user in secrets file in openshift?

Comment: Unexpected error running Liquibase: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=APPUSER;CREATE PROCEDURE; [Failed SQL: (-551) CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE out_put.delete_recipient_GDPR_SP (IN inDocumentOrderId int, OUT out_list_recipientId varchar(40)) - This is the error I am getting

Comment: It got solved after the appuser user got elevated permissions.